# Android animators, start position of animation

Tags: android, animation, animator

Im using animator and i need current position to start animation.

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "x",
                                         current position, 1);
```

How i can get current position of my button?

Comment: You can use `button.getX()` and `button.getY()` to get the coordiantes of the top left corner of your button. If you need the center you can add `button.getWidth() / 2` to that.

Comment: My mistake, that button is Relative Layout, named button. So i get 0 from 'button.getX()'. Is there any way to get position of Relative Layout?

Comment: You have to wait one frame so the system lays out your views and set their sizes correctly. You can do this by creating a runnable and posting it to one of your views. On the next frame this runnable will be executed and you will get the correct size:
`yourView.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    int realX = button.getX();
   }
  });`